# Not able to access static imported class attributes

Tags: angular

My Angular 9 app.component

```
import {Config} from './config';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

 ngOnInit(){
 console.log(Config.version); // prints undefined
}
```

My config at same level

```
export class Config {
  static version: string = '0.0.1';}
```

BUT it on app.template {{config.version}} works

I have tried the same importing that class from a service with same result.

In other angular project (8v), my config class attributes are accessible from app.component.
Any ideas for fixing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need set `config = Config;` and use direct `Config.version`

Your code work corrected.

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1h4rza

Comment: Thanks, I tried before, but it does not make any difference.